# PHP Code retrieving data from a database shows blank page

Tags: php, arrays, database, sqlite

I am using SQlite database for this.

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('scrapycrawler/items.db');

$results = $db->query('SELECT title,url FROM iteeems');
   while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
   foreach ($row as $rows) {
      echo $rows['link'];
   }
  }
?>
```

It basically shows me a blank page with no source when i clicked "view source" in Chrome. I do think this might be relevant but i am running out of disk space locally with only MBs of space left, not sure if this might affect local-Server folder syncing.

Here is a picture of my database browser with the columns, those are just placeholders and do not represent actual data. [image: **[Picture](http://puu.sh/eifgb/5692932af7.png)**]

Comment: Have you checked if your query even returns anything?

Comment: Is the SQLite3 extension enabled on your server, and do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: A blank page in PHP usually means that there was an error server-side.  Turn on error reporting in PHP, check the PHP logs, etc.

Comment: @Koen Yes it does, but only does it with this code showing code unformatted http://puu.sh/eigD1/ed37b1f48a.png.

Comment: What happens if you remove the foreach and instead of that do echo $row['link'];

Comment: @Don'tPanic Mind elaborating ? I did 
sudo apt get install php5 sqlite3

Comment: Oh, yeah, it looks like the foreach is unnecessary.

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers Shows a blank screen, never had this.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ironically, did not work without forreach. Showed a blank page.

Comment: Did you also change $rows['link'] to $row['link']?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, tested both options.

Comment: what exactly does print_r($row) return?

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers Basically, all the database content mashed together, needed to use the forreach loop too. http://puu.sh/eiiKl/c92b80f022.png

Comment: Yea as im reading here, fetchArray() only fetches the first row, so  in that case your foreach was right, can you try echo 
$rows[0]['link'] and $rows[0], since the documentation says it can get returned as a numeric array.

Comment: oh hahahaha damn we're looking over something, there is no link in your database, i knew we were missing something :p

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers As seen in the picture, it gives a string of random letters that has nothing to do with the data in the link/url column or  column 0 http://puu.sh/eilQ3/c04b557a96.png

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers Haha, coincidentally, that was one of the database items, url = item['link']

Comment: so did you get it done? if not check my last answer update

Comment: Yeah, i did reply you to that, prolly some Website issue. Ok, this is the answer that i posted :  
@KoenHoeijmakers As seen in the picture, it gives a string of random letters that has nothing to do with the data in the link/url column or column 0 puu.sh/eilQ3/c04b557a96.png

Comment: I don't see any random letters in your question. what are you talking about? could you provide your database file?

Comment: @KimAlexander Opps, sry, replied wrong person, yeah, did that and still produces a blank page

Comment: did you check my last comment  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868576/php-code-retrieving-data-from-a-database-shows-blank-page/27869071#comment44142041_27869071   ?  query('SELECT title,url FROM iteeems ORDER BY id LIMIT 10'); ?

Comment: Why did you call your table `iteeems` (with 3 e's), when they store *items* ? Or is that a typo?

Comment: No, i named the table that actually.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to echo out `link`, but you're not selecting that column from your database. If `link` is not in fact a column in your database, you can at least echo out `title` and `url` using the below code.

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('scrapycrawler/items.db');

$result = $db->query('SELECT title,url FROM iteeems');

while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {

    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['url'];
}
?>
```

Comment: there is no LINK column on the screenshot ;-)

Comment: Right you are. I have deleted the offending code and description from my answer, without adding anything new.

Comment: Yeah, tried what u suggested and still produced a blank page.

Comment: could you provide your items.db file?

Answer (score 1):

I am not SQLite specialist;

but isn't it weird?

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT title,url FROM iteeems');
   while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
   foreach ($row as $rows) {
      echo $rows['link'];
   }
  }
```

you are selecting two fields TITLE and URL but trying to echo LINK? should it really work?

try:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT title,url FROM iteeems ORDER BY id LIMIT 10');
   while($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

      echo $row['url'];

  }
```

Comment: Did what u suggested previously , did did nothing too. Selecting is the query part, sort of like "what kind of fishes do i want to buy to keep stocked in my fridge for use anytime."

Comment: just updated code a little, you had weird WHILE structure I didn't notice before

Comment: sorry, just reread documentation, it seems while is acceptable but some new changes :-)

Comment: After trying it a few times( ur first code), echoing $row instead work but did something like this http://puu.sh/eiuR9/399e4a1985.png

Comment: that is strange :-) check please, or change the screenshot in your question to prove that it is values in ITEEEMS table :-) and check updated select ORDER plus LIMIT